# Ping a remote host from a remote network

Tags: networking, ping, nat, remote-connection, cisco-router

I am trying to ping the remote host E1 (please see the below Network activity Diagram in cisco Packet tracer) from another host in network A1, but am not able to ping, the ping fails. Somebody gave me a hint that the NAT is blocking the ping. Could somebody help me how I can solve this problem and ping E1 successfully?

[image: network diagram]

Comment: That looks a lot like it is a network diagram for an organization with multiple locations. So first question is - are these all connected on a VPN as a single centralized network? or are these served individually by their own internet connection and you are trying to connect through the internet?

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. They are not connected via VPN and yes I am trying to ping from one location to another via their own internet connection. Sorry but I don't know why would I need VPN in this case?

Comment: What are the addresses, subnets, routes on each computer and router?

Comment: You wouldn't need a VPN, but whether or not it is a VPN changes the troubleshooting steps. Since it is over the Internet, the endpoint is almost certainly using NAT, unless it happens to have a public IP, so when you ping that address, you're targeting a private IP that technically doesn't exist from the perspective of your machine and no route exists to get to it. Answering @grawity's question will help clarify if that is the case.

Comment: @grawity I am not able to upload another foto here, so I am providing a link for configuration file of all devices in the picture above: Remote Branch: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hkVT-cuDw6MOS75j52Gxl68QAK0w7AHz/view?usp=sharing  ,                       Config-File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jlt4WRgRNliljrpVACF7DcDcFhV0Ky1U/view?usp=sharing